# No package iperf3 available CentOS

Tags: yum, centos7, iperf

I'm trying to install iperf3 on a server to run some tests...
Unfortunately I cannot. What do I need to do? Enable a repo or download a rpm file with wget?

```
[root@localhost hodor]# yum install iperf3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.otenet.gr
 * extras: ftp.otenet.gr
 * updates: ftp.otenet.gr
No package iperf3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's in EPEL, so you have to to enable that repo first;

```
 yum install epel-release
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're running CentOS 6 you can download the epel-release RPM as you won't have the epel-release package in the repo. wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm && rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 1):

Update for CentOS7. iperf3 is in the base repo now rather than epel.
So `yum install iperf3` will work.